# I Enabled my Google drive API, but still I got error code "Project has not enabled the API."

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

As you can see in the image below Google drive API is enabled

[image]

And when I run my code I got error that tell me:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Project has not enabled the API. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Project has not enabled the API. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
```

}

I used service account methodology, and I also try  OAuth2.0 client id, and i got the same error.

Is there something i missed for enabling driver api.

Note:

- Scope I am trying to use (DriveScopes.DRIVE "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive")

  - I set all the info that need in Driver UI integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for helping
I found the issue in my code, I used this line

```
Operation op = service.scripts().run(scriptId, request).execute();
```

where it required to have the following api also (Google Apps Script Execution API) where I have to enable it...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one you need Drive SDK as well.

[image]

Comment: Thnx @dalmTo i try to search for Drive SDK but I didn't find I got "No results for Drive SDK" in Google APIs section.
Can u tell me the steps of enable it?